# Facing Angular-6 deployment error on github

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages

I am following this tutorial to deploy the angular app using github.
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-deploy-an-angular-application-to-github
at last, I am facing this error
[image]

commands which I used to deploy the app are:-

```
 npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
$ ng build --prod --base-href https://sahilkatia.github.io/resume/
```

(where sahilkatia is my user name and resume is my repository name)

and at last

```
ngh -no-silent
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of your resume repository:

```
https://github.com/sahilkatia/resume/tree/gh-pages/resume
https://github.com/sahilkatia/resume/blob/gh-pages/resume/index.html
```

The gh-pages branch should include your resume content directly, not a folder resume with your resume content

That is, you should be able to access `index.html` directly with:

```
https://github.com/sahilkatia/resume/blob/gh-pages/index.html
```

Comment: I didn't understand properly. But I am feeling it can solve my issue

Comment: Anglar6 have different deployment now

Comment: @san could you try by moving the content of the resume folder to the root folder of the gh-pages branch?

Comment: in dist I have resume folder which further have index.html file, but if I see path, it directlt gies to dist/index.html but it should be dist/resume/index.html

Comment: Actually I don't know where is gh-pages branch, I am just folliwng the tutorial for the deployment of my app

Comment: I solved this by https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/issues/37#issuecomment-388589863

but now its giving me errors